# Blazor doesn't redirect to https on heroku

Tags: ssl, redirect, heroku, .net-core, blazor

I've deployed my Blazor (.Net Core 3.1) WebApp on Heroku with a hobby Dyno for automatic certificates.
But my App isn't redirecting to https.

My Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // BLAZOR COOKIE AUTH CODE
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();
        //END

        //services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("DataSource=app.db"));
        //services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(options =>
        {
            options.DetailedErrors = true;
        }).AddHubOptions(o =>
        {
            o.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
        });
        //services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, ServerAuthenticationStateProvider>();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
        services.AddSingleton<HairStylistService>();
        services.AddSingleton<EmployeeService>();
        services.AddSingleton<SettingsService>();
        services.AddSingleton<HairCutTypeService>();
        services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationService>();
        services.AddSingleton<TimeService>();
        services.AddSingleton<EmployeeHairCutTypeConnectionService>();
        services.AddSingleton<TimeBoxService>();
        services.AddScoped<ToastService>();
        services.AddScoped<IFileUpload, FileUpload>();
        ApiConfig.Configure("hairapp","live_k0pY4VCc6PHbNqfJL6cd2bG6C1UcubJoO3");


        // BLAZOR COOKIE AUTH CODE
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddScoped<HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddHttpClient();
        services.AddScoped<HttpClient>();
        // END
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            //app.UseHsts();
            app.UseHsts();
        }


        app.UseRouting();

        // BLAZOR COOKIE AUTH CODE
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        // END

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            // BLAZOR COOKIE AUTH CODE
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            // END
        });
    }
}
```

Has somebody an idea how I can redirect from http to https?

I tied to redirect with NavigationManager in the Index after Initializing, but then I have too many Request exception.

I deploy my App with bitbucket Pipelines. Here is the yml.

```
# This is a sample build configuration for .NET Core.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/5Q4SMw for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: microsoft/dotnet:sdk

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - dotnetcore
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - git push https://heroku:KEY@git.heroku.com/PROJECT.git HEAD
With this buildpack: https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack
```

Thank you!

Comment: How do you deploy your app ?

Comment: I deploy my App with bitbucket Pipelines.

Comment: Edit your question instead of add an answer

Comment: I did. Thank you for the hint. Do you know a solution for me?

Comment: Try to set https port and kestrel listening url using env var ASPNETCORE_URLS, ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT. doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#require-https  
Not sure it'll work

Comment: Thank you. It was a good idea. I set https://DOMAIN to the urls env var ASPNETCORE_URLS and 443 to the ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT, but now there appears the exception ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Maybe you should not set ASPNETCORE_URLS or set it with `https://+`

Comment: I've tested it, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Do you know why it redirects ? Is there something in your log explaining why ?

Comment: I have no logs from the middleware. How can I activate them?
I removed app.UseHttpsRedirection and then it doesn't redirect. The env vars are active.
Do you need my Appsettings?

Comment: Try to setup HttpsRedirection and ForwardedHeadersOptions https://stackoverflow.com/a/61205136/136699

Comment: Did you set ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password with your certificate password if any and ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path with the path of your certificate? And, as @jincod mentions you need to setup `ForwardedHeadersOptions`

Comment: The Solution from @jincod was right. Thank you very much for your help. It is now secure.